# OpenCV to close the contour - Python

Tags: image-processing, opencv, python

I am working on extracting data from various financial forms and for which I need to close the contours of attribute 3a, 5b, and 6a (just like it is currently for attribute 4a) so that I can extract these closed boxes from the form and then use OCR to read the info inside the boxes.

I understand that I can use OpenCV morphological operations on this to identify shape but since it is not a defined shape like circle, ellipse or rectangle so don't know how to proceed with this.

Thanks for your help guys, greatly appreciate it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AphPi.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest looking to see if you can read the data beside the 3a, 5b, etc without a full boarder.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is finding the binary mask. Then you can use the mask to find the boxes.

---

- 1. Load the image and convert it to the HSV color-space
- 2. Get binary mask
- 3. Display contours.

---

- 1. **Load the image and convert it to the HSV color-space**

     - The reason we convert it to the HSV is that we want to discriminate the objects (boxes) from the rest of the image. To discriminate the certain objects, converting to HSV format is generally used as the first step. [source1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Use_in_image_analysis), [source2](http://coecsl.ece.illinois.edu/ge423/spring05/group8/FinalProject/HSV_writeup.pdf)
- 2. **Getting the binary mask**

     - Mask operation will help the identify the boxes in the input image.
     - [image]
- 3. **Display contours**

     - From the mask, we can detect the box locations.
     - [image]

---

Code:

```py
import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("AphPi.png")

# Convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Get the binary mask
msk = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array([0, 0, 0]), np.array([0, 255, 235]))

# Find and grab contours
cnt = imutils.grab_contours(cv2.findContours(msk.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE))

# Draw the contours
cv2.drawContours(img, cnt, -1, (0, 0, 255), thickness=5)

# Display
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```